# Angular routing change in url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-routing

I am making angular 7 application where i am making redirection via router and auth guard..

**Html:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tsu2sm?file=app%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html

```
<p *ngIf="showUserRoute">
  <a [routerLink]="['/user']">User</a>
</p>
<p><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Logout</a></p>
```

Here you could able to see a **ngIf**,

```
<p *ngIf="showUserRoute">
  <a [routerLink]="['/user']">User</a>
</p>
```

For which the **ts:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tsu2sm?file=app%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {

let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

 console.log(user.token);

 if(user.token == "fake-jwt-token") {
   this.showUserRoute = false;
 }

}
```

Here if `user.token == "fake-jwt-token"` then i should not allow the user to navigate to `user` url..

**It hides the url now**, No issue regarding it..

The issue is even though `<a [routerLink]="['/user']">User</a>` kept in hidden, an user **can change the url** manually so if he makes the url like,

**Adding user at last in url**

`https://angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tsu2sm.stackblitz.io/user`, it is redirecting to user page..

My requirement is if the user changes the url like the above, it should not be allowed and the redirection needs to happen to previous state..

You can explore **working stackblitz** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tsu2sm

and you can get what i am in the need..

In the stackblitz if you give `https://angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tsu2sm.stackblitz.io/user` then it will redirect to user component, but whereas our home page has a condition if the logged in user has `"fake-jwt-token"` then the user is strictly not allowed to access the `user` url and component..

**Edit**

**I am not asking to prevent from login**, the user can logged in and can taken to home component but if the user has `fake-jwt-token`, then he was not allowed to go to `/user` url alone but he can access other page..

User having `fake-jwt-token` can logged in successfully but need protected from going into `https://angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tsu2sm.stackblitz.io/user`

**Step 1:**

User can login using test and test as username and password

**Step 2:**

After giving the credentials user will be redirected to home component.

**Step 3:**
Now the logged in user has `fake-jwt-token` so after logged in restrict him from accessing `user` component so if he gives url like this from home component `https://angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tsu2sm.stackblitz.io/user` , then redirect back to home component..

Kindly help me to block the user being enter into user route url with "fake-jwt-token"..

Comment: You mean changing the route url directly after you have logged In once? It works fine if you haven't logged In.

Comment: @xyz, As of logged in no issues but after logged in if the tokenis fake jwt token then user was not allowed to access the user component and so he cannot move to users url by directly..

Comment: Then why miss applying condition you applied in your Home Component in your Auth Guard :D

Comment: @xyz, Sorry i am unable to get you.. I am new in angular and so i am unable to block the users from such redirection even after logged in based on fake jwt token.. And hence asked for help please help me with the same stackblitz i have provided for my better understanding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your Auth Guard with the same condition you have in your Home Component.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let currentUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')): null;
    if (currentUser && currentUser.token != "fake-jwt-token") {
        // logged in and doesn't have fake token
        return true;
    }
    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
    return false;
}
```

A simple and clean way to achieve this would be to have seperate guard for HomeComnponent.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HomeGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
      let currentUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
        if (currentUser) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And have your routes like:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [HomeGuard] },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-42ft5j?file=app%2F_guards%2Fhome.guard.ts

Comment: @undefined: Can check here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-42ft5j?file=app%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.ts

Comment: If i give test and test in login username and password respectively, it was not redirecting home component.. Kindly recheck the stackblitz..

Comment: @undefined: You are correct, it should not. Because that user has `fake-jwt-token`

Comment: I am not sure whether i have explained clearly.. User can login and can go to home component but he cannot go to user component alone if he has ```fake-jwt-token``` but he can go everywhere after logged in..

Comment: Only users router link was restricted for the user having ```fake-jwt-token``` but he can succefully loggedin and can taken to home page.. No issues in it..

Comment: Also updated my question, please help me i hope you are good in this and can give me better solution..

Comment: @undefined: Got it, you have to either create a different guard for User or update the `Auth` guard so that it checks the token in case you are redirecting to users. I will update the answer.

Comment: I hope you got my point please update you answer with working stackblitz..

Comment: In simple after logged in if the user changes the url like ```https://angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tsu2sm.stackblitz.io/user```, then it should not take to user component rather it can taken to home component itself because user has ```fake-jwt-token```..

Comment: It shows only ```app.component.html``` content and nothing else.. Unable to see login page.. If the login screen was there oly then i can check for results.. Kindly check for it please..

Comment: If i give manually ```https://angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-42ft5j.stackblitz.io/login?returnUrl=%2Fuser``` with credentials for login then it again redirecting to login page.. For me it should redirect to home component.. Because the login is successfull but the user has fake token so block him from acessing user link..

Comment: @undefined: I see, I have updated it. You can check now.

Comment: Can you explain why the product page was not redirected https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-z8nqnm

Comment: Sorry i need to completely check for it, i have added ``` <a [routerLink]="['/product']">Product</a>``` but it is not redirecting to product component.. Why??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185021/discussion-between-xyz-and-undefined).

Answer (score 1):

You should have made the change in your `AuthGuard` as your `''` and `'user'` routes are already protected by it.

Change your implementation of the `AuthGuard` to the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const userFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    let currentUser = userFromStorage ? JSON.parse(userFromStorage) : null;
    if (currentUser) {
      if(currentUser.token !== "fake-jwt-token" || route.component.name !== 'UserComponent') {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        return true;
      }
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-42ft5j?file=app%2F_guards%2Fauth.guard.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Redirection to home component not happening after loggedin.. It was showing loading for long time and nothing happens.. Can you check for it please??

Comment: Thanks fpr your solution kindly read my edited question.. User can logged in but he should not allow to access only ```/user``` router link if he has ```fake-jwt-token```..

Comment: Yeah. Because you have the AuthGuard configured on only the `''` and the `'/user'`  paths.

Comment: How can i change that as per my requirement.. I think i have given the requirement little clear now.. User can logged in and can go to home page but he cannot acces the user ```routerlink``` alone.. Please help me to achieve the result..

Comment: In simple after logged in if the user changes the url like ```https://angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tsu2sm.stackblitz.io/user```, then it should not take to user component rather it can taken to home component itself because user has ```fake-jwt-token```..

Comment: For all the routes that you want to guard against `fake-jwt-token` as the value of the `user.token`, apply the `AuthGuard`. That's something that you've done in the `app.routing.ts` file. If you don't want this guard to be applied on the `HomeComponent`, just get rid of the `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` from the route config object of `{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, ... }`

Comment: I need to have ```canActivate: [AuthGuard]``` for all the routes but whereas after successful log in, if the user has ```fake-jwt-token``` then i am hiding the click ```<p *ngIf="showUserRoute">
  <a [routerLink]="['/user']">User</a>
</p>``` you can see but user can change the url manually know?? so if he changed manually also it should be restricted and user component should not get opened..

Comment: @undefined, updated my answer. Check to see if this helps.

Comment: I hope you are almost done except a thing, if the url was given with ```/user``` then its not accepting but it was not redirecting back to home.. I am getting empty content with ```app.component.html``` text at bottm.. i am not having home component content..

Comment: Please check and update for it.. if the user gives ```/user``` then it should redirect back to ```home``` component with same content it has..

Comment: I think this was the only problem still there.. If its cleared then we are done..

Comment: @undefined, just updated. Check if that works. I've tested it out and it does.

Comment: Can you explain why the product page was not redirected https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-z8nqnm ??

Comment: Sorry i need to completely check for it, i have added ```  <a [routerLink]="['/product']">Product</a>``` but it is not redirecting to product component.. Why??

Comment: Because there is no config specified for the `product` route. So this will be handled by the catch all route(`'**'`) which will redirect the user to the empty route(`''`) which would eventually load the `HomeComponent`.

Comment: Thanks SiddAjmera for your valuable time for me.. But from both the two answers i am able to accept only one.. I will go with xyz and your solution also most impoertant for me.. Thanks for your time and help..

Comment: @SiddAjmera I believe, checking the component name is not a good idea. I guess a production build will not preserve the component name.

Comment: I actually was trying to check for the route name first. But it was coming as undefined. Therefore I switched back to ComponentName. Would you please add a link to support your statement? I'm interested in knowing about it in a greater detail.